# Dropping DB table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In my work project, For 'Drop DB Schema' option, table is getting dropped. But in code, i could see any 'drop table' command.  My question is how table will be dropped without the above command

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear - are you saying that there's a table being dropped and you want to know how that can happen?

Comment: yes.  Table is getting dropped without 'drop table' command. I want to know how this can be possible?

Comment: There is no `drop schema` in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

> For 'Drop DB Schema' option, table is getting dropped.

That is not possible in SQL. When you say **schema**, it is nothing but a **user** in Oracle. So, DROP user will drop the user itself.

The syntax to **DROP** a **table** is:

```
DROP TABLE table_name;
```

For example,

```
SQL> create table t(a number);

Table created.

SQL> drop table t;

Table dropped.
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I can think of two possible scenarios where a table is being dropped without an explicit `DROP TABLE` command:

- the owner is being dropped, i.e. `DROP USER u1 CASCADE` will drop the user u1 and all the objects that belong to this user (tables, views, ...)
- the table belongs to a materialized view, and the materialized view wasn't created on a prebuilt table. In that case, a `DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW mv1` will drop the materialized view mv1 as well as the associated table mv1